# Tap event and tapped item

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a multiselect ListBox from the Toolkit and I want to show the tapped item in a new page.
How can I extract every item from the tapped item? Every item has 4 fields.

This is the code that fills the ListBox:

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, 
                                    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{         
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        string xml = e.Result;
        XDocument data = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var persons = from query in data.Descendants("Table")
        select new MailList
        {
            Sender = (string)query.Element("FromUser"),
            Body = (string)query.Element("Message"),
            Date = ((DateTime)query.Element("mDate")).ToString("MM/yy"),
            Time = (string)query.Element("mTime"),
        };
         EmailList.ItemsSource = persons;
    }
}
```

I want to send to the other page the Sender and the Body field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple...

On the other page, create a public static variable called SelectedMailingList of type MailingList.

On tap, set the other page's SelectedMailingList property and then Navigate to the page.

have a look at this sample.. I use the same mechanism..
http://wp7pivottest.codeplex.com/

Comment: can you write me an example? Thanks

Comment: I didn;t find any relation for what i'm looking for in your example.
I want to take the sender and the body of the tapped item in the listbox.
Thank s again

Comment: the selected item on listbox will be an instance of the class. all you need to do is set the static property of the page you want to send it to

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing Navigation Query Strings Parameters described in below links

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/223044.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring(v=vs.95).aspx

Its easy to implement, I hope it helps